# Interview test about the clousure in the javascript?

Tags: javascript, closures

This is an interview question! And I can't know the reason of it!

```js
function fun(val) {
  this.x = val;
  return this;
}

var x = fun(1);
var y = fun(2);

console.log(x.x); //I can't understand this result.
console.log(y.x);
```

Comment: `this` in the function `fun` refers to the `window`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with closures?!

Comment: @Bergi I agree, it's more to do with the use of the `this` keyword

Comment: This code will neither work in strict mode nor in a local (e.g. module) scope. It's horrible code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that happens because "This" in the fun function refers to Window object not a local thing inside the function. so therefore you first call it by fun(1) and make the window.x = 1, and then call it by fun(2) and it becomes window.x = 2 .. then you console log it when both x and y are a reference to window ... and therefore both will have the same final value.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function the "normal" way, the `this` object points to the global object (`window`):

```js
function testFunction () {
  return this;
}

console.log(window === testFunction());
```

This means that what your function returns is the global object, and both variables `x` and `y` are references to the global object. Before it returns, it assigns a property `x` to the global object.

In the first function call, it assigns `1` to the property `x` of the global object. In the second function call, it assigns `2` to the *same property*. This is why you get `2` two times.

If you want `this` to refer to another object than the global one, you have to use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```js
function testFunction (value) {
  this.x = value;
  return this;
}

var firstObject = {};
var secondObject = {};

var x = testFunction.call(firstObject, 1);
var y = testFunction.call(secondObject, 2);

console.log(x.x);
console.log(y.x);

console.log(x === firstObject);
console.log(y === secondObject);

console.log(window === testFunction());
```